# If there is a common value between two ranges, display that value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet which I use as a simple check in/out system for camera equipment within a school.

Each student wears an ID card which, when scanned, returns a unique number to the [BASKET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLQPg.png) range (A2:A20). The ID numbers look like this: 16-293914

When I scan a students ID card into the basket, I want the script to look up this number from the [list of Students](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASLic.png) (W22:W166) and return the students name matching the ID number to the NAME cell (D3).

For example:
Number is scanned into basket.
If there is a common value in studentID.
Return firstName + lastName of the student to cell E3.
Run checkOut() function.
If no match: do nothing.

This is my script, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

```
//student name auto fill
function onEdit(e) {
  var basket = sheet.getRange('A2:A20').getValues();
  var name = sheet.getRange("D3").getValue();
  var studentID = sheet.getRange('W22:W166').getValues();
  var firstName = sheet.getRange('Y22:Y166').getValues();
  var lastName = sheet.getRange('X22:X166').getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<studentID.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<basket.length;j++) {
      if(studentName[i][0]==basket[j][0]){
        name[i][0]= firstName + lastName;
      }
    }
  }
  checkOut()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I came up with.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //Not sure where your 'sheet' variable comes from. If it's global you will want to remove this next line.
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet(); //OR e.source.getSheetByName("<YOUR SHEET NAME>");

  var basket = sheet.getRange('A2:A20').getValues();
  var name = sheet.getRange("D3");
  var studentID = sheet.getRange('W22:W166').getValues();

  // These are kind of wasteful, lets wait to pull just the first and last name we need.
  //var firstName = sheet.getRange('Y22:Y166').getValues();
  //var lastName = sheet.getRange('X22:X166').getValues();

  var flag = false; //Flag lets us know later if match was found.
  for(var i=0;i<studentID.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<basket.length;j++) {
      if(studentID[i][0] !== "" && basket[j][0] !== "" && studentID[i][0]==basket[j][0]){
        var sName = sheet.getRange("X"+(22+i)+":Y"+(22+i)).getValues(); //Now get the name... This is a bit weird, but it works. Normally I'd use other getRange() params.
        name.setValue(sName[0][1] + " " + sName[0][0]); //Set cell D3 to firstname lastname.
        flag = true;
      }
    }
  }
  if(flag) checkOut(); //Only run if match found.
}
```